# How do I pass cookies from an HttpURLConnection to WebDriver in Java?

Tags: java, http, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a website that requires some basic authentication.  Upon successful login a session key is sent back in cookies.  I've written some code to get this cookie via the web service.  It ends like this:

```
public List<HttpCookie> getCookies(String Domain, String user, String pass) {
    // Actual services to log in here
    List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println(cookie);
        }

    return cookies;
}
```

When I debug I can see my `sessionKey` in there with a valid value.  It's got the same `domain` that I passed above, and a blank path like `/`.

Here's how I've tried adding the cookie to my WebDriver instance:

```
List<HttpCookie> cookies = getCookies(DOMAIN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {                                                                    
    String cookieName = cookie.getName();                                                              
    String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();                                                            
    String cookieDomain = cookie.getDomain();                                                          
    String cookiePath = cookie.getPath();                                                              
    Date cookieExpiry = new Date();                                                           
    Cookie selCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieDomain, cookiePath, cookieExpiry);          
    driver.manage().addCookie(selCookie);                                                              
}                                                                                                      
driver.get(ROOT_URL+"/some/internal/page");
```

When I try to add `selCookie` I get the following error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: You may only set cookies for the current domain
```

I'm copying the domain directly from the cookie I received.  I even tried passing it as a bare String instead of relying on the `getDomain()` method, but it returned the same error.  Any idea what could be causing it to complain?

Comment: Is the host name in `ROOT_URL` same as `DOMAIN`?

Comment: your selCookie-domain may not current domain. Selenium only supports to set cookie for current domain.

Comment: @srkavin: Yes, the host name in `ROOT_URL` matches `DOMAIN`, and both match the domain I get back in my cookies from the initial login service call.

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang: By current domain, do you mean the domain of the URL that WebDriver is currently trying to access?  If that's the case, then the strings do match.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  Since the login sequence was the first thing I was doing, I hadn't gotten to any URL with `driver` yet, so its current domain was empty, not a match for `cookieDomain`.  To fix this I need to send `driver` to `ROOT_URL` before I populate the cookies.

Comment: happy that you could fix it

Answer (score 0):

To add a cookie to a WebDriver instance, the domain in the cookie has to match the current domain of the WebDriver instance.  I was trying to add the cookie before `driver` had visited anything, so `driver`'s current domain was blank.  I fixed it by just sending `driver` to `ROOT_URL` before I retrieve the session cookie and add it to `driver`:

```
 //Added this:
driver.get(ROOT_URL);

List<HttpCookie> cookies = getCookies(DOMAIN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {                                                                    
    String cookieName = cookie.getName();                                                              
    String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();                                                            
    String cookieDomain = cookie.getDomain();                                                          
    String cookiePath = cookie.getPath();                                                              
    Date cookieExpiry = new Date();                                                           
    Cookie selCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieDomain, cookiePath, cookieExpiry);          
    driver.manage().addCookie(selCookie);                                                              
}                                                                                                      
driver.get(ROOT_URL+"/some/internal/page");
```